# Function is being called with type in front of it: (T)func(param1, param2). What is this called and what is it for?

Tags: c#

Function is being called with type in front of it: (T)func(param1, param2). What is this called and what is it for? I'd assume it's coercing a return type?

Again, the pattern takes the form:

```
(T)func(params)
```

example:

```
(int)Mathf.Log(level, 2f) // it's an example from unity, level is of type int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(T)` is an explicit cast. See the docs here, under the "Explicit Conversions" title: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

The `func(params)` bit is just a method call. The cast is not part of it, you're just casting the result.

```
// cast the result of a method call
var i = (int)Mathf.Log(level, 2f);

// cast a random object
var s = (string)someObject;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a pattern per se (depending on what exactly you mean by "pattern")... it's just C#. It sounds like maybe you're confused by the fact that it *appears* a method is being converted to a primitive type?

What it's actually doing is converting the return type of [Mathf.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Log.html) (a `float`) to an `int`.

So this:

```
int log = (int)Mathf.Log(level, 2f);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
float result = Mathf.Log(level, 2f);

int log = (int)result;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx) ; [`Math.Log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd50b6h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `double` so a cast is needed to make it an `int` (truncating the result)